# How to disable curve closing in OneNote + Bambo Pen?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, pen, bamboo

I am trying to draw y-like shapes but somtimes it turns them automatically to 9-like shapes,

[image]

I emphasize that I never drew horizontal caps like in shapes #6 and #7

How to disable this "feature"?